# Saving a class object without serialization

Tags: java, android, object, save, storage

i have a class named MyClass, with a few attributes String name, String place, int num....
I read android developer site but i dont realy understand how it works.
So i want a method which save these into a file or somewhere, and when i want to read it, from another activity or anywhere i can put it to an array or something so i get g.Name, g.place and the other attributes.

And i also want to be able edit and delete these.

If anyone knows a good solution please write. And sorry for my english.

Comment: If you wish to save the values of `MyClass` somewhere _outside_ the scope of your application (for example to `SharedPreferences` or a file), you will have no choice but to serialize the data. This of course assumes you want access to this data _after_ your application is closed. Now if you just wish to save the data for _while_ your application is running, you can use something along the lines of a singleton, global class, etc.

Comment: You can save your class in any way as long as you have a methode for saving it and an other metode to create your object from a file

Comment: yes but i read that if i serialize my class, if i modify that class, it wont work anymore, so first i just want to test if what i wrote is working.

Comment: In general Serialization can work when the type changes as long as the changes are done in a compatible way.  The Serialization spec has more information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#6519

Comment: thanks i think there is no other way, i have to serialize it, i make a backup than:)

Answer (score 0):

`SharedPreferences` is one option that is easy to use.  There is a good guide for getting started with them here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: No.  You will have to put the primitive values (String, int, boolean) into SharedPreferences.  Since you mentioned that your class only has a few attributes, this seems like it would be a practical approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XStream which is able to serialize any object to XML (of course with some assumptions). It's slower than serialization but in your case it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JacksonJSON or gson from google. That way you can write objects to a file and read it again.